# Powershell script to get IPv4 only

Tags: powershell, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

I'm trying to get IPv4 only from my computer which has multiple IPv4 addresses.
The output contains IPv6 also as below:

```
10.24.21.115
fe80::8029:4127:55a6:4328
192.168.0.2
fe80::ac59:de9a:c9db:b5d8
```

Tried filtering like $_.ipaddress -notlike "fe80*" and many more...

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled=TRUE' | where { $_.ipaddress -notlike "fe80*" } | select-object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
```

Expected output as :
10.24.21.115,
192.168.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled=TRUE' |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress |
  Where-Object { $_ -match '(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}' }
```

Comment: Thanks, will try shortly.